# Symfony2 - related entity contains 'isDefault' property how to use in related entity form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have 2 related entities, e.g. Book and Publisher (Book has one publisher, publisher has many books).

When editing\adding a Book I want to present a select of the Publishers.

Publishers has a property 'isDefault' on of the Publisher records will be marked as isDefault TRUE.

How do I make use of this in my add/edit form to pre-select the default Publisher?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend injecting publisherRepository as a service into your form.
And then declare a field something like this:

```
$builder->add('publishers', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $this->publisherRepository->findAll(),
    'data' => $this->publisherRepository->findOneBy(['isDefault' => true]),
));
```